# ubuntu server 12.04.01 don't have internet

Tags: networking

There is no GUI installed and below are useful information about my server:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface. I disabled this one.
#auto lo 
#iface lo inet loopback 

# The primary network interface 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.4.20   
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.4.1
broadcast 192.168.4.255

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination          Gateway          Genmask          Flags     Metric     Ref        Use        Iface
0.0.0.0              192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0             UG         0           0           0              eth0
192.168.4.0          0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0      U           0           0           0               eth0

$ ifconfig -a
eth0   Link encamp:Ethernet HWaddr 04:06:ff:aa22:33
        inet addr:192.168.4.20 Bcast:192.168.4.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueueln:1000
        RX Bytes:684 (684.0 B) TX bytes:600 (600.0 B)]

lo     Link encamp:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
        UP LOOBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
        RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueueln:0
        RX Bytes:4336 (4.3 KB) TX bytes:4336 (4.3 KB)
```

I have done everything possible but I can't ping Google's DNS or any URL.

Comment: What's "everything possible". Can you ping `192.168.4.0`?

Comment: Maybe 192.168.4.1?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, sry... Wouldn't make much sense pinging the network address. Ping 192.168.4.1 instead. Also, please add the output of `sudo iptables -L` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: @the_Seppi the output of Sudo iptable -L:                                     Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Yes i can ping 192.168.4.1 and all other devices on the network. Also, the other devices on the network have internet

Comment: Please add this as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, the loopback interface is required and must not be removed. I suggest you amend the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to this:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

# The primary network interface 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.4.20   
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.4.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
```

Get the system to re-read and use the amended file:

```
sudo ifdown -a && sudo ifup -a
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: I did as you say but ping test was not successful

Comment: Guys, thanks for your support. I have pfsense in my network with an application called "Captive Portal". The mac address of the server was not in the application so it was blocking the internet on the server. Thanks for all your help